# Properly check if word is in string?

Tags: python, string

Say, for example, I want to check if the word `test` is in a string. Normally, I'd just:

```
if 'test' in theString
```

But I want to make sure it's the actual word, not just the string. For example, `test` in "It was detestable" would yield a false positive. I could check to make sure it contains `(\s)test(\s)` (spaces before and after), but than "...prepare for the test!" would yield a false negative. It seems my only other option is this:

```
if ' test ' in theString or ' test.' in theString or ' test!' in theString or.....
```

Is there a way to do this properly, something like `if 'test'.asword in theString`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import re
if re.search(r'\btest\b', theString):
    pass
```

This will look for word boundaries on either end of `test`. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), `\b`:

> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character.

Comment: 8 minutes to go. *sigh*. Thanks for the answer, hadn't thought of regex, despite using it in the example!